# C sockets close connection if no response

Tags: c, sockets, timeout

I have a small problem with waiting for response from client. The code looks like this:

```
    num_bytes_received = recv(recvFD, line, MAX_LINE_SIZE-1, 0);

    if(line[0] == 'R')
    {
        do_something();
    }

    if(line[0] == 'P')
    {
        do_another_thing();
    }
```

Is there any simple way to wait for a message let's say 30 seconds and if there's no message execute do_another_thing(); function? It's not connection problems situation (like clients disconnect etc.). It's my own limitation I would like to create.

Comment: You can use `select` with a timeout to wait for activity on the socket. Or `setsockopt` using `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use select() with timeout.

```
int ret;
fd_set set;
struct timeval timeout;
/* Initialize the file descriptor set. */
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(recvFD, &set);

/* Initialize the timeout data structure. */
timeout.tv_sec = 30;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

/* select returns 0 if timeout, 1 if input available, -1 if error. */
ret = select(recvFD+1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout));
if (ret == 1) {
    num_bytes_received = recv(recvFD, line, MAX_LINE_SIZE-1, 0);
    if(line[0] == 'R')
    {
        do_something();
    }

    if(line[0] == 'P')
    {
        do_another_thing();
    }
} 
else if (ret == 0) {
    /* timeout */
    do_another_thing();
}
else {
    /* error handling */
}
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you!